# java - Missing JavaFX application class com.example.filesengine.MainFile не находит главный файл

Tags: java, javafx, maven

У меня вылетает `java` проект с ошибкой:

```
\fe>java --module-path "D:\Рабочий стол\fe\lib\javafx-sdk-21.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar FilesEngine.jar
Missing JavaFX application class com.example.filesengine.MainFile
```

Содержимое проекта:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Содержимое `scr.json`:

```
{
  "FirstScript": "com.example.filesengine.TestScript"
}
```

Код `MainFile`:

```
package com.example.filesengine;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class MainFile extends javafx.application.Application {
    Pane layout = new Pane();
    static boolean ExitUpdate = false;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello!");
        String FilesEnginePath = System.getenv("APPDATA");
        FilesEnginePath = FilesEnginePath + "\\FilesEngine";
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300.0, 250.0);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        ObjectList behavior = new ObjectList();
        JSONParser parserScript = new JSONParser();

        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("scr.json"))
        {
            //Read JSON file
            java.lang.Object obj = parserScript.parse(reader);
            JSONArray ListScr = (JSONArray) obj;
            System.out.println(ListScr);

            for (int i = 0; i == ((JSONArray) obj).size()-1; i++) {
                String scr = (String) ((JSONArray) obj).get(i);

                try {
                    Class<ObjectList> c = (Class<ObjectList>) Class.forName(scr);
                    Constructor<ObjectList> s = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
                    ObjectList w = s.newInstance();
                    w.startC();
                } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("Скрипт не найден!");
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event->{ExitUpdate = true;});
        behavior.update(layout);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>FilesEngine</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FilesEngine</name>
  
    <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>  </properties>
  
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>20-ea+2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>20-ea+2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>20-ea+2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>20-ea+2</version>
      </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
  
  
    </dependencies>
  
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.11.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>20-ea+2</source>
            <target>20-ea+2</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.8</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
              <id>default-cli</id>
              <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.filesengine/com.example.filesengine.MainFile</mainClass>
                <launcher>app</launcher>
                <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
```

MainFile2:

```java
package com.example.filesengine;

public class MainFile2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFile.main(args);
    }
}
```

MainFile:

```java
package com.example.filesengine;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MainFile extends javafx.application.Application {
    Pane layout = new Pane();
    static boolean ExitUpdate = false;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello!");
        String FilesEnginePath = System.getenv("APPDATA");
        FilesEnginePath = FilesEnginePath + "\\FilesEngine";
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300.0, 250.0);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        ObjectList behavior = new ObjectList();
        JSONParser parserScript = new JSONParser();

        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\IdeaProjects\\FilesEngine\\src\\main\\java\\com\\example\\filesengine\\scr.json"))
        {
            //Read JSON file
            java.lang.Object obj = parserScript.parse(reader);
            JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray scr_list = (JSONArray) jobj.get("scripts");
            if (scr_list != null) {
                Iterator<String> scr = scr_list.iterator();
                while (scr.hasNext()) {
                    try {
                        Class<ObjectList> c = (Class<ObjectList>) Class.forName(scr.next());
                        Constructor<ObjectList> s = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
                        ObjectList WW = s.newInstance();
                        WW.startC();
                    } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("Скрипт не найден! ClassNotFoundException");
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        System.out.println("Скрипт не найден! NoSuchMethodException");
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        System.out.println("Скрипт не найден! InvocationTargetException");
                    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                        System.out.println("Скрипт не найден! InstantiationException");
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        System.out.println("Скрипт не найден! IllegalAccessException");
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event->{ExitUpdate = true;});
        behavior.update(layout);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что не обнаружен именно .jar файл?  Согласно [документации](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/latest/index.html), класс `JSONParser` находится в пакете `org.json.simple.parser`.

Comment: См. [JSON simple not found when JAR file is in class path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138759/): вероятно, следует добавить эту зависимость в `module-info`.  Насчёт минуса -- не тратьте нервы :)  Могли поставить его, так как не хватает деталей в вопросе, несмотря на три скриншота.

Comment: теперь у меня ошибка `Missing JavaFX application class com.example.filesengine.MainFile`

Comment: Теперь вам нужно либо отредактировать текущий вопрос, либо создать новый, но в любом случае требуется описать новую проблему и указать все существенные детали.

Comment: @NowhereMan вы знаете как это решить?

Comment: В манифесте .jar файла указан `Main-Class`?  Пробовали запустить, указав свой .jar файл в `classpath`: `java ... -cp FilesEngine.jar  com.example.filesengine.MainFile`?

Comment: да, указан Main-class, пробовал запускать и через `-cp`, но результата это не дало, та же ошибка

Comment: Странное название файла в `pom.xml`: `<mainClass>com.example.filesengine/com.example.filesengine.MainFile</mainClass>`, для чего там указан путь к пакету?  Ещё один вариант "обходного" решения описан здесь: [Maven JavaFx project compiles but running from console give "Missing JavaFX application class" error msg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861520/) -- может потребоваться обёртка для JavaFX класса.

Comment: та же самая ошибка `Missing JavaFX application class com.example.filesengine.MainFile` (тут не `Missing JavaFX application class com.example.filesengine.MainFile2`) новый файл я назвал `MainFile2.java` и указал его в `pom.xml`, но ничего не поменялось

Comment: эту проблему возможно решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я забыл указать модуль в `--add-modules`.

У меня было так: `java --module-path "...\javafx-sdk-21.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar out\artifacts\FilesEngine_jar\FilesEngine.jar`,

a надо было так: `java --module-path "...\javafx-sdk-21.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,json.simple -jar out\artifacts\FilesEngine_jar\FilesEngine.jar`