# maven & javaFX - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile

Tags: java, javafx, maven

пишет, что неправильная версия.

Java 21

`maven`:

```
mvn clean javafx:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.example:FilesEngine >-----------------------
[INFO] Building FilesEngine 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ FilesEngine ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\IdeaProjects\FilesEngine\target
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> javafx:0.0.8:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ FilesEngine >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ FilesEngine ---
[INFO] Copying 2 resources from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ FilesEngine ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files with javac [debug target 20-ea+2 module-path] to target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.340 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-29T20:45:33+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project FilesEngine: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 20-ea+2 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>FilesEngine</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FilesEngine</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>20-ea+2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
      <version>20-ea+2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
      <version>20-ea+2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
      <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
      <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
      <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>20-ea+2</source>
          <target>20-ea+2</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.example.filesengine/com.example.filesengine.MainFile2</mainClass>
              <launcher>app</launcher>
              <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
              <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
              <noManPages>true</noManPages>
              <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
              <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `maven-compiler-plugin` устанавливается [версия **JDK**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html), а не **JavaFX**, поэтому следует исправить `pom.xml` на корректную версию JDK (в данном случае 17):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>17</source>
        <target>17</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Неправда, если вы изменили версию Java, у вас должно было как минимум измениться сообщение об ошибке от `maven`.  Выполните в консоли команду `mvn -version` и приведите результат её вывода.

Comment: там же 17 JDK///

Comment: у меня почему то стоял другой `java home`

Comment: Странно, что пропала зависимость на json.simple из этого варианта `pom.xml`.  Неделю назад она [была на месте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/)

Comment: скомпилировал через `mvn clean javafx:run` и теперь `jvm` не находит манифест