# java - не находит главный файл javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, maven, jvm

Я скомпилировал через команду `mvn clean javafx:run` (во время компиляции проект запускается без ошибок), запаковал через `mvn package`, но у меня при запуске проекта вылетает ошибка:

```
PS D:\IdeaProjects\FilesEngine> java -cp ./target/FilesEngine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.filesengine.MainFile --module-path "D:\javafx-sdk-21.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar ./target/FilesEngine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.filesengine.MainFile
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
PS D:\IdeaProjects\FilesEngine>
```

если я запускаю через независимый к javaFX класс у меня вылетала ошибка `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
PS D:\IdeaProjects\FilesEngine> java -cp ./target/FilesEngine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.filesengine.MainFile2 --module-path "D:\javafx-sdk-21.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar ./target/FilesEngine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        at com.example.filesengine.MainFile2.main(MainFile2.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        ... 10 more
PS D:\IdeaProjects\FilesEngine>
```

если запускать без `-cp`:

```
PS D:\IdeaProjects\FilesEngine> java --module-path "D:\javafx-sdk-21.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar ./target/FilesEngine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar                                                                  
no main manifest attribute, in ./target/FilesEngine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
PS D:\IdeaProjects\FilesEngine>
```

Содержимое `MainFile2`:

```java
package com.example.filesengine;

public class MainFile2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFile.main(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте запустить Ваше приложение следующим образом:
java --module-path "D:\javafx-sdk-21.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -cp ./target/FilesEngine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.filesengine.MainFile

Comment: @TaranenkoAnt тогда выводит `Missing JavaFX application class com.example.filesengine.MainFile`

Comment: я заметил, что в Ваших скриптах присутствуют классы MainFile  и MainFile2, вы оба класса наследуете от Application? И у обоих есть метод main?

Comment: нет, MainFile это сам проект, а MainFile2 это файл, запускающий MainFile

Comment: А что делает данная строчка MainFile.main(args); ? Если MainFile это проект, а не класс, и зачем Вам javaFx?

Декстопные Fx приложения запускаются примерно так:

public class MainFile2 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    }
}

Вы наследуетесь от класса Application и переопределяете метод старт, в мейне запускаете launch(args)

Comment: MainFile это класс

Comment: Данный вопрос является [дубликатом этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/java-missing-javafx-application-class-com-example-filesengine-mainfile-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам главный файл не читался, т. к. в нем импортировалась библиотека, которая не была указана в параметре `--add-modules`.